# Filtering files with the given range of inputin perl

Tags: linux, shell, perl, unix

The perl script which takes an input i.e name of the file, I need to find all the files that matches with that pattern.

```
Example: given input as 2019052300 2019052323 (YYYYMMDDHH)
```

Here, I need to fetch all the files that named with 2019052300 to 2019052323. like 2019052300,2019052301.. 2019052323.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: You are expected to make an effort. Also see [Strange and maddening rules](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2018/04/23/strange-and-maddening-rules/) and [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158289).

Answer (score 2):

It's easy enough to generate a list of the timestamps that you're interested in. In this code, I've used [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) which has been part of the standard Perl distribution since version 5.10 in 2007.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

@ARGV == 2 or die "Usage: $0 <start> <end>\n";

my ($start_str, $end_str) = @ARGV;

my $format = '%Y%m%d%H';

my $start = Time::Piece->strptime($start_str, $format);
my $end   = Time::Piece->strptime($end_str,   $format);

my $curr  = $start;

while ($curr <= $end) {
  say $curr->strftime($format);
  $curr += ONE_HOUR;
}
```

This might give you problems over a period where daylight saving time either starts or ends. Fixing that is left as an exercise for the reader :-)